How can the starting values be vectorized before optimization, where should this be installed, at what point does the back transformation take place?
General goal: I want to optimize parameters from the Rosenbrock function with the minimize function in a Python script. My result is already good but I want to use vectorization for the whole optimization process.
Here is my code without the vectorization:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the Rosenbrock function
def rosenbrock_function(x):
    return np.sum(100.0 * (x[1:] - x[:-1]**2)**2 + (1 - x[:-1])**2)

# Lists to store iteration count and objective function values
iteration_count = []
objective_values = []

# Callback function to append iteration count and objective value
def callback_function(xk):
    iteration_count.append(len(iteration_count) + 1)
    objective_values.append(rosenbrock_function(xk))

# Initial guess
x0 = np.array([-2, 2])

# Perform optimization
result = minimize(rosenbrock_function, x0, method='powell', callback=callback_function)

print(f"Optimal solution: {result.x}")
print(f"Minimal objective value: {result.fun}")

# Plotting the iteration process
plt.plot(iteration_count, objective_values, marker='o', linestyle='-')
plt.xlabel('Iteration')
plt.ylabel('Objective Value')
plt.title('Iteration Process of Objective Value (Rosenbrock Function)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

My results without vectorization:

    Optimal solution: [1. 1.]
    Minimal objective value: 5.0330755563491266e-26


I know the results are perfect but I am looking for a way to use the power of vectorization for this example.

I want to implement kind of a code like this:
def normalize_vector(x):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(x)
    if norm == 0:
        return x
    return x / norm

def renormalize_vector(x, target_norm):
    print(target_norm)
    norm = np.linalg.norm(x)
    if norm == 0:
        return x
    return x * (target_norm / norm)

But in the current state, it doesn't work and I get bad results. What am I doing wrong? Is there a general approach?
Here is a solution with the vectorization:
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the Rosenbrock function
def rosenbrock_function(x):
    return np.sum(100.0 * (x[1:] - x[:-1]**2)**2 + (1 - x[:-1])**2)  # Calculate the Rosenbrock function value

# Lists to store iteration count and objective function values
iteration_count = []
objective_values = []

# Function to normalize a vector
def normalize_vector(x):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(x)
    if norm == 0:
        return x
    return x / norm

# Function to renormalize a vector to a target norm
def renormalize_vector(x, target_norm):
    norm = np.linalg.norm(x)
    if norm == 0:
        return x
    return x * (target_norm / norm)

# Callback function to append iteration count and objective value
def callback_function(xk):
    iteration_count.append(len(iteration_count) + 1)  # Append the iteration count
    objective_values.append(rosenbrock_function(xk))  # Append the objective function value
    target_norm = np.linalg.norm(x0)  # Target norm based on the initial guess
    xk = renormalize_vector(xk, target_norm)  # Renormalize the current solution

# Initial guess
x0 = np.array([-2, 2])
x0 = normalize_vector(x0)  # Normalize the initial guess

# Perform optimization
result = minimize(rosenbrock_function, x0, method='powell', callback=callback_function)

print(f"Optimal solution: {result.x}")
print(f"Minimal objective value: {result.fun}")

# Plotting the iteration process
plt.plot(iteration_count, objective_values, marker='o', linestyle='-')  # Plot iteration count vs. objective value
plt.xlabel('Iteration')  # Label for x-axis
plt.ylabel('Objective Value')  # Label for y-axis
plt.show()  # Display the plot

and i get this result:
Optimal solution: [1. 1.]
Minimal objective value: 1.9721522630525295e-31

But i think the re-normalization part in the callback function is at the wrong place? I expect it after results=minimze(...)

What isn't vectorized about your first approach?

I am lost in what you want to achieve, maybe specify what do you mean by term "vectorization. Side note: target_norm = np.linalg.norm(x0) could be pre-calculated. No need to do it over and over again in the callback
